# Astro dev, failing with vite:import-analysis on internal package when using pnpm

Tags: node.js, vite, pnpm, astrojs

I have a Astro frontend in my PNPM monorepo, but whenever I try to run it with `astro dev` I get an unusual error like the following

```
5:21:51 PM [vite] Internal server error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS s
yntax. If you are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: /project/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_@types+node@20.7.0/node_modules/vite/dist/clie
nt/env.mjs:4:0
  1  |  const context = (() => {
     |  ^
  2  |      if (typeof globalThis !== 'undefined') {
  3  |          return globalThis;
      at formatError (file:///project/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_@types+node@20.7.0/node_m
odules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:43993:46)
      at TransformContext.error (file:///project/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_@types+node@20
.7.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:43989:19)
      at TransformContext.transform (file:///project/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_@types+nod
e@20.7.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:41740:22)
      at async Object.transform (file:///project/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_@types+node@20
.7.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:44283:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///project/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_@types+node@20
.7.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:54950:29)
      at async viteTransformMiddleware (file:///project/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_@types+
node@20.7.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:64345:32)
```

I usually try to debug this myself but I have no idea what is happening or what to search for. Why is it even trying to analyze `node_modules`, why are these `+` directories being created in the `node_modules`, some pnpm black magic probably?

```
➜ ls node_modules/.pnpm/ | grep vite
@astrojs+preact@3.0.0_@babel+core@7.23.0_preact@10.17.1_vite@4.4.9
@astrojs+react@3.0.2_@types+react-dom@18.0.6_@types+react@18.0.21_react-dom@18.0.0_react@18.0.0_vite@4.4.9
@preact+preset-vite@2.5.0_@babel+core@7.23.0_preact@10.17.1_vite@4.4.9
@prefresh+vite@2.4.1_preact@10.17.1_vite@4.4.9
@vitejs+plugin-react@4.1.0_vite@4.4.9
vite@4.4.9_@types+node@20.7.0
vitefu@0.2.4_vite@4.4.9
```

I am pretty certain that `pnpm` and the way it handles dependencies is messing with the `vite`, but I have another `astro` frontend in the same monorepo which is working just fine, all thought that one is using `preact` instead of `react`.

`package.json`

```json
    "dependencies": {
        "@astrojs/react": "3.0.2",
        "@astrojs/tailwind": "5.0.0",
        "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "5.3.1",
        "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.3",
        "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.5",
        "@radix-ui/react-select": "^1.2.2",
        "@radix-ui/react-slot": "1.0.2",
        "astro": "3.0.12",
        "aws-amplify": "^5.3.11",
        "class-variance-authority": "0.7.0",
        "clsx": "1.2.1",
        "lucide-react": "0.105.0-alpha.4",
        "react": "18.0.0",
        "react-dom": "18.0.0",
        "tailwind-merge": "1.13.2",
        "tailwindcss-animate": "1.0.6",
        "zod": "^3.22.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "18.0.21",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
        "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
        "typescript": "5.1.6"
    }
```

This is from `pnpm-lock.yaml`

```
  /@vitejs/plugin-react@4.1.0(vite@4.4.9):
    resolution: {integrity: sha512-rM0SqazU9iqPUraQ2JlIvReeaxOoRj6n+PzB1C0cBzIbd8qP336nC39/R9yPi3wVcah7E7j/kdU1uCUqMEU4OQ==}
    engines: {node: ^14.18.0 || >=16.0.0}
    peerDependencies:
      vite: ^4.2.0
    dependencies:
      '@babel/core': 7.23.0
      '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-self': 7.22.5(@babel/core@7.23.0)
      '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source': 7.22.5(@babel/core@7.23.0)
      '@types/babel__core': 7.20.2
      react-refresh: 0.14.0
      vite: 4.4.9(@types/node@20.7.0)
    transitivePeerDependencies:
      - supports-color
    dev: false

  /astro@3.0.12(@types/node@20.7.0):
    resolution: {integrity: sha512-nDLI9OGEjYIX90a1Md1orqyurPxqXTWTy7Sm3ZsWl5dpzSjcUXo3VB/GTvNjAMS9sE40BOxhay7/hnnQuI8p7A==}
    engines: {node: '>=18.14.1', npm: '>=6.14.0'}
    hasBin: true
    dependencies
```

Any way to resolve this or to exclude the node_modules from the `vite` check?